# djutils queue command not being discovered

Tags: python, django, multithreading, task-queue

I am trying to use [django-utils](http://charlesleifer.com/docs/djutils/index.html) to start a lot of of commands asynchronously, in parallel threads (These commands deal 99.99% with I/O). However, I keep getting the following error:

```
QueueException: MyProject.maintenanceInterface.commands.queuecmd_refreshDataAsync not found in CommandRegistry
```

the function refreshDataAsync is in commands.py inside maintenanceInterface - and maintenanceInterface is in the list of installed apps.

I am running the queue consumer like so:

```
python .\manage.py queue_consumer
```

When I look at the queue consumer log, it will tell me that it has found the function (at init):

```
djutils.commands.queuecmd_delayed_resize
djutils.queue.queue.QueueCommand
djutils.queue.queue.PeriodicQueueCommand
maintenanceInterface.commands.queuecmd_refreshDataAsync
2012-04-18 16:57:10,598:djutils.queue.logger:INFO:Starting periodic command execution thread
```

and still throw the exception.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Not a straight forward answer but indeed a nice suggestion, just use celery and django celery to do this async processing.

You can do everything you with django-utils (at least in terms of async) and much more (lots of backends, any kind of setting/parameter you can name you have it), there are also few  related projects that use celery to do things async (eg. you want to send emails using celery you write 0 lines of code, there's an app for that.)

Comment: Next version of the system will use celery.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the consumer was importing the same library as the django codebase - but with a slightly different path.

The consumer was importing

```
maintenanceInterface.commands.queuecmd_refreshDataAsync
```

And the code was explicitly calling the package above it:

```
WepPlatform.maintenanceInterface.commands.refreshDataAsync
```

So the consumer was unable to match and would not run the command.